# Sound over (TCP)IP (NO streaming question)

Tags: linux, audio, http, remote-control

I search for software / software parts that allow to:

1.) interprete data packages (sent by IP, TCP or HTTP from other machines) to be "sound information" and play it. i.e. there will be data like "1500x3x1, 4500x2x0.2" means: play 1500hz tone three times for 1 second

2.) receive and store short Mp3 (or similar) files and the, upon request, play that "sound pieces"
i.e. first, get a file and an "id" (id might be "ring" or "fault") and then, later, some other senders might send a "play::ring" or "play::fault" data package to make the device tune as requested.

Ideally that software will run on a RasPi or similar single board computer.

Anyone having hints/links/directions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Play 1500 Hz tone with what shape? Sine, saw, rectangle? Play it at what volume? Fade in or fade out? As you can imagine, there are dozens of more possibilities. Someone who has implemented this, may have implemented much more than you need. This again, probably makes the "commands" not so simple.

Comment: Another question: given the RasPi plays the sounds, what is the device you want to use for controlling the RasPi? Basically you need 2 pieces of software, one which runs on Raspbian and another one which runs on Android, Windows or whatever.

Comment: Well ... of course one can make it very complex. My use case is "simple": in IoT world, you will have a number of devices spread around and users want to get some feedback if a "command" (like a button pressed) will be recognized.

I want to have a device "in the middle" (hallway, rooms etc) that can just play a simple tune sent by a device. MAYBE one more parameter might be used for the volumen (night vs. day or so). Of course this has nothing to do with things like streaming or similar. Also, I can adjust to the "given" protocol of the device.